# Making a clock autorefresh using setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

i wanted to build a clock and my only problem here is that setInterval basically does not work. Am I missing something

```
const timer = document.getElementById("container")
let currentTime = new Date()

let hours = currentTime.getHours()
let minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
let seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()



function time () {

        let hoursIf = hours.toString().length==1 ? "0"+hours : hours
        let minutesIf = minutes.toString().length==1 ? "0"+ minutes : minutes
        let secondsIf = seconds.toString().length==1 ? "0" +seconds : seconds

        timer.textContent = `${hoursIf}:${minutesIf}:${secondsIf}`

}
time()
let run = setInterval(time, 1000)
```

Comment: It's not `setInterval` - you *never* update `currentTime`, so `setInterval` runs every second and generates a time string from the exact same date object.

Comment: Hey, I can't see timer defined anywhere, is your question missing something out of the pasted scope? How are you checking the time after setting up the setInterval? Also why are you calling the function once before setting the interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, trust me. The problem is the assigment in:

```js
let hours = currentTime.getHours()
let minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
let seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()
```

You're assigning time once at the start, and don't check for updated values later. If you'd put that in your time function it would work properly.
Something like this:

```js
function time () {
        let currentTime = new Date()

        let hours = currentTime.getHours()
        let minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
        let seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()

        let hoursIf = hours.toString().length==1 ? "0"+hours : hours
        let minutesIf = minutes.toString().length==1 ? "0"+ minutes : minutes
        let secondsIf = seconds.toString().length==1 ? "0" +seconds : seconds

        timer.textContent = `${hoursIf}:${minutesIf}:${secondsIf}`

}
time()
let run = setInterval(time, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't updating your variables. You have them as globals, but never update their values, so the method "time" keeps using the same values.

```
let currentTime = new Date()

let hours = currentTime.getHours()
let minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
let seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()
```

These should be set in your method or at least updated to current values. Otherwise you are simply re-displaying the same time every `time` executes.

If you put a "Console.log" in your method, I'd bet you'd see that it does run, it just doesn't update the time as you expect.